# How to mark bad blocks on HDD?

Tags: hard-drive

My NAS HDD has failed to boot. So I decided to check and mark badblocks HDD via following commands attaching to Ubuntu.

```
sudo badblocks -sv /dev/sdb > /tmp/bads.txt

sudo e2fsck -l /tmp/bads.txt /dev/sdb
```

Unfortunately, I receive the following error. Would you please inform how I can mark the bad blocks discovered by badblocks command.

```
e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
e2fsck: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
e2fsck: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdb

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
        e2fsck -b 32768 <device>

Found a gpt partition table in /dev/sdb
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You ran **e2fsck** on the **whole drive** not on the partition where the filesystem lies.

Also you should note that you should use the same **blocksize** with *badblock* than the fs uses.

So to achieve what you want in a much simpler way, you can simply run:

```
sudo fsck -vck /dev/sdbx
```

This will run a filesystem check but also check for badblocks and add them to the filesystem.

You can double the `c` to run `sudo fsck -vcck /dev/sdbx` instead to force a *non-desctructive read-write badblock tes*t.

Don't forget to change the `x` to the number of your partition. And the `b` to something else if the drive is attached with a different name.

Assuming your filesystem is ext4 (or ext3 or ext2 ...)

Comment: Should your first sentence be the opposite? "You run e2fsck on the whole drive not on the partition ..."  But then your example runs fsck on a partition (sdbx) not the drive (sdb). Perhaps the first sentence is meant to read "You ran ..."?

Comment: I tried this with the read-write test, took many hours and after finishing I started copying big files to the new filesystem and still got errors. Not sure if it's a problem of the command or the disk, but anyway in my case it was better to throw the disk away